# error finding main method in class: org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap : org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap

Tags: wso2

I am trying to install WSO2 as a Windows Service and meet the following error.
error finding main method in class: org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap : org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap

My wrapper.conf is :

wrapper.java.classpath.3 = ${carbon_home}\repository\components\plugins\commons-lang_2.6.0.wso2v1.jar

## ********************************************************************

## working directory

## ********************************************************************

wrapper.working.dir=${carbon_home}\

## Java Main class.

## YAJSW: default is "org.rzo.yajsw.app.WrapperJVMMain"

## DO NOT SET THIS PROPERTY UNLESS YOU HAVE YOUR OWN IMPLEMENTATION

## wrapper.java.mainclass=

## ********************************************************************

## tmp folder

## yajsw creates temporary files named in_.. out_.. err_.. jna..

## per default these are placed in jna.tmpdir.

## jna.tmpdir is set in setenv batch file to /tmp

## ********************************************************************

wrapper.tmp.path = ${jna_tmpdir}

## ********************************************************************

## Application main class or native executable

## One of the following properties MUST be defined

## ********************************************************************

## Java Application main class

wrapper.java.app.mainclass=org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap

## Log Level for console output.  (See docs for log levels)

wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO

## Log file to use for wrapper output logging.

wrapper.logfile=${wrapper_home}/log/wrapper.log

## Format of output for the log file.  (See docs for formats)

## wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM

## Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)

## wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO

## Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before

## the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value

## of 0, disables log rolling by size.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kB) or

## 'm' (mB) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.

## If wrapper.logfile does not contain the string ROLLNUM it will be automatically added as suffix of the file name

wrapper.logfile.maxsize=10m

## Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old

## files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.

wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=10

## Title to use when running as a console

wrapper.console.title="WSO2 Carbon"

## ********************************************************************

## Wrapper Windows Service and Posix Daemon Properties

## ********************************************************************

## Name of the service

wrapper.ntservice.name=WSO2CARBON

## Display name of the service

wrapper.ntservice.displayname="WSO2 Carbon"

## Description of the service

wrapper.ntservice.description="Carbon Kernel"

## ********************************************************************

## Wrapper System Tray Properties

## ********************************************************************

## enable system tray

wrapper.tray = true

## TCP/IP port. If none is defined multicast discovery is used to find the port

## Set the port in case multicast is not possible.

wrapper.tray.port = 15002

## ********************************************************************

## Exit Code Properties

## Restart on non zero exit code

## ********************************************************************

wrapper.on_exit.0=SHUTDOWN

wrapper.on_exit.default=RESTART

## ********************************************************************

## Trigger actions on console output

## ********************************************************************

## On Exception show message in system tray

wrapper.filter.trigger.0=Exception

wrapper.filter.script.0=scripts/trayMessage.gv

wrapper.filter.script.0.args=Exception

## ********************************************************************

## genConfig: further Properties generated by genConfig

## ********************************************************************

placeHolderSoGenPropsComeHere=

wrapper.java.command = ${java_home}\bin\java

wrapper.java.classpath.1 = ${java_home}\lib\tools.jar

wrapper.java.classpath.2 = ${carbon_home}\bin\*.jar

wrapper.app.parameter.1 = org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap

wrapper.app.parameter.2 = RUN

wrapper.java.additional.1 = -Xbootclasspath/a:${carbon_home}\lib\xboot\*.jar

wrapper.java.additional.2 = -Xms256m

wrapper.java.additional.3 = -Xmx1024m

wrapper.java.additional.4 = -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

wrapper.java.additional.5 = -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

wrapper.java.additional.6 = -XX:HeapDumpPath=${carbon_home}\repository\logs\heap-dump.hprof

wrapper.java.additional.7 = -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote

wrapper.java.additional.8 = -Djava.endorsed.dirs=${carbon_home}\lib\endorsed;${java_home}\jre\lib\endorsed

wrapper.java.additional.9 = -Dcarbon.registry.root=/

wrapper.java.additional.10 = -Dcarbon.home=${carbon_home}

wrapper.java.additional.11 = -Dwso2.server.standalone=true

wrapper.java.additional.12 = -Djava.command=${java_home}\bin\java

wrapper.java.additional.13 = -Djava.io.tmpdir=${carbon_home}\tmp

wrapper.java.additional.14 = -Dcatalina.base=${carbon_home}\lib\tomcat

wrapper.java.additional.15 = -Djava.util.logging.config.file=${carbon_home}\repository\conf\tomcat\tomcat-log.properties

wrapper.java.additional.16 = -Dcarbon.config.dir.path=${carbon_home}\repository\conf

wrapper.java.additional.17 = -Dcarbon.logs.path=${carbon_home}\repository\logs

wrapper.java.additional.18 = -Dcomponents.repo=${carbon_home}\repository\components\plugins

wrapper.java.additional.19 = -Dconf.location=${carbon_home}\repository\conf

wrapper.java.additional.20 = -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.file=${carbon_home}\lib\transactions.properties

wrapper.java.additional.21 = -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.hide_init_file_path=true

wrapper.java.additional.22 = -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true

wrapper.java.additional.23 = -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.authentication=simple

wrapper.java.additional.24 = -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout=3000

wrapper.java.additional.25 = -Dorg.terracotta.quartz.skipUpdateCheck=true

wrapper.java.additional.26 = -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false

wrapper.java.additional.27 = -Dfile.encoding=UTF8

wrapper.java.additional.28 = -DworkerNode=false

wrapper.java.additional.29 = -Dorg.wso2.ignoreHostnameVerification=true

Answer (score 0):

I found that this error occurs when the yajsw\bat\installService.bat has not been executed ahead of the running the yajsw service.

Please also ensure that:

- The %EI_HOME%\bin\yajsw\wrapper.conf is copied to YAJSW\conf directory
- The carbon_home environment variable is set to the root directory of the WSO2 EI installation